# youtube Video not downloading in mobile

Tags: php, video, youtube

In the php, youtube video is downloading fine on desktop, but on mobile its downloaidng with .html extension. Also when Downloading the video, it not shows filesize, How can I fix it please help...

```
<?php
$downloadURL = urldecode($_GET['link']);
$type = urldecode($_GET['type']); // mp4, 3gp , mp3
$title = urldecode($_GET['title']);
$fileName = $title.'.'.$type;


if (!empty($downloadURL) && substr($downloadURL, 0, 8) === 'https://') {
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($fileName));
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Pragma: public");
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($downloadURL);
}
?>
```

Help me to download the videos in mobile as well as in the desktop, and also it should show filesize when downloading. How can I fix these both issue?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe mobile rename the download video format. kindly use the below code. It might be helpful to you.

I have added multiple mobile user-agent.

```html
<?php
$downloadURL = urldecode($_GET['link']);
$type = urldecode($_GET['type']); // mp4, 3gp , mp3
$title = urldecode($_GET['title']);
$fileName = $title.'.'.$type;

if (!empty($downloadURL) && substr($downloadURL, 0, 8) === 'https://') {
    $ch = curl_init($downloadURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
    curl_close($ch);

    if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Android') ||
        strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'webOS') ||
        strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') ||
        strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad') ||
        strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod') ||
        strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Windows Phone')){
            $fileName = $title.'.'.$type;
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
        }else{
            header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($fileName));
        }
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Pragma: public");
    header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($downloadURL);
}
?>
```

Comment: If I'll using this:  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($downloadURL));   then download not start on mobile and on pc it downloaded but downloaded file is 0kb size

Comment: The video is downloading fine on mobile, thanks, but size not showing in pc and mobile.

Comment: ok. let me update my existing code.

Comment: Yeah, sure take your time.

Comment: Now it is working fine, thanks for the help. God bless you!

Comment: @Loveyatri Please mark the the answer as correct, so others know there is a working solution here. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @Loveyatri. If you need anything more connect with LinkedIn.

Comment: Yes, I have already marked it immediately, but it shows you should have at least 15 reputations. I just register today, so not have anything,